# How to get values from stdin to string

Tags: c

I can use an only exit, open, close, write, read, malloc
, and free.
why doesn't it write the buffer to a string?

```c
file = 0;

char *ft_stdin(int file)
{
    char    buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    char    *str_map;
    int     r;

    str_map = malloc(sizeof(*str_map) * BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    while ((r = read(file, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) == '\0')
    {
        buffer[r] = '\0';
        str_map = buffer;
    }
    return (str_map);
}
```

Comment: `str_map = buffer;` assigns a pointer, you want to copy the *contents* (e.g.: using `strcpy` or by manually iterating)

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks you!! Work

Comment: `read()` returns number of bytes read. You're comparing it to 0 for some reason. Also, you're leaking memory: allocating str_map and then overwriting it without freeing.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a temporary variable. Undefined behaviour. `strdup` if you must.

Comment: Are you looking for the last match? Or all matches?

Comment: Note: `sizeof(*str_map) * BUFFER_SIZE + 1` works for char, but not for others. You want `sizeof(*str_map) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

1. You are declaring dynamic memory inside a function, this is wrong because you can loose your reference and never free the memory, many C functions takes a pointer as argument because it's programmer work to allocate/free memory.
2. You are assing a local scope memory addres, wich is in the stack to a heap memory addres, so when the functions returns, you loose buffer content, unlike anoter languajes, in C, you need to copy strings with a library function.

So with this two comments, you would like to do this.

Outside the function you allocate memory:

```
 char * str_map = malloc(.....);
```

And modify your function to this:

```
char *ft_stdin(int file, char * ptr)
{
    ....

    while ((r = read(file, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) == '\0')
    {
       buffer[r] = '\0';

       // Here you actually are copiying the string.
       for(int i = 0; i <= r; i++) {
          ptr[i] = buffer[i];
       }
    }
    return (str_map);
}
```

You need make sure not overflowing the ptr variable and then freeing it.

You can use static memory if you want, but the key concept is that you cant return local function scope memory address, and you need to copy string by hand or by strcpy in C.